# When I Unplug the dongle and plug it back again to USB on Raspberry pi the pi detects the modem but doesn't get connected to internet.

Tags: pi-3

Im using 4G airtel dongle to connect  internet on Raspberry pi , Im able to auto connect successfully to the internet when the Pi is booted.

My issue is as follows:

I have removed the dongle from the USB of Pi and when I plug it back again it doesn't connect to internet,but the Pi recognizes as modem (wwan0). Im using wvdial to connect  internet.

Can anyone please help with the solution why the pi is unable to connect to internet when it is replugged ?

Comment: Try restarting network manager:  sudo service network-manager restart

Comment: Yes, it can be done, but my case is I want to automate it must automatically connect to internet connection when it is re-plugged.

Comment: You can write /etc/udev/rules.d/50-myUSB.rules file and make it run certain command everytime the device (certain ID_Vendor and ID_Product) is pluged in. Can you just try if you need the "sudo" part of the command in your OS on RPi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a rules file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` folder and make it run a bash script when your USB device is connected. For this you need to find the ID_Vendor and ID_Product code of device. Run `lsusb` command. There you will see something like `Bus 003 Device 005: ID ffff:0005.` In this case `idVendor = ffff` and `idProduct = 0005`. Yours will be different.

Than create for example `50-myUSB.rules` file in the above directory with content something like (change ID_vendor and ID_product):

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="ffff", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"`

This will run `script.sh` every time you will plug in the device. Now you have to create the `script.sh` with content something like:

`#! /bin/bash
service network-manager restart`

(Somebody can propose better script.)
Now you have to give it execution permitions:

`chmod +x script.sh`

I am not sure if you need to restart the OS or not for the changes to take effect.

[Click here if you want to know more about udev rules.](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)